# distributed torch data collision from all_gather (writing all_gather results to file "fixes" the problem)

Tags: python, distributed, torch

Problem:

- a distributed process computes errors and returns them alongside `float` indices
- when errors are gathered from the separate ranks, there's collision happening on these indices

  - so if the dataset has 100 samples and the number of GPUs is 4, the resulting set of indices will be of length 25 instead of the expected 100
- when I write each rank's data (pre-gather) to file, I can verify that the indices are 100% disjoint
- when I write each rank's data (post-gather) to file, the issue disappears
- comment out the post-gather debug data file writing, the issue returns

NOTE: printing out the post-gather results also "fixes" the issue, but sorting the post-gather results does not.

So something about writing the post-gather data to file is resolving some distributed shenanigans...I'm reminded of the need to `flush` streams to avoid unexpected results, but I don't see any kind of corollary in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#torch.distributed.all_gather).

Here's a minimal example that shows what's going on in my code:

```
# setup_distributed_stuff()
rank = torch.distributed.get_rank()
world_size = torch.distributed.get_world_size()

# Data returned from distributed computation.
# Note that there's no overlap between the different ranks.
data = torch.arange(
    0 + (rank * 100 // world_size),
    (rank + 1) * 100 // world_size,
)

# `data` is confirmed to be disjoint across ranks by writing to file here.

# Gather data from all ranks.
if world_size > 1:
    all_data = [torch.zeros_like(data) for _ in range(world_size)]
    torch.distributed.all_gather(all_data, data)
    data = torch.cat(all_data, dim=0)

    # By writing "data" to file for debugging, the problem goes away...
    #     i.e. len(set(data.numpy())) == 100!
    # If I comment this out, then my gathered data collides...
    #     i.e. len(set(data.numpy())) == 100 // world_size
    with open("debug_data.pt", "wb") as _file:
        torch.save(data, _file)

    # I can also simply print the indices and get the same effect...
    logger.info(
        "Gathered result indices: {}...{}".format(
            data[:10, -1], data[-10:, -1]
        )
    )

    # However, sorting the indices doesn't do me any good...
    data = data[data[:, -1].argsort(dim=0)]


if rank == 0:
    # do_something(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `torch.distributed.barrier()` call after the `all_gather()` call fixes the issue in a more satisfying manner. I didn't think to do this because the docs state that `all_gather()` is a blocking call. Perhaps they mean blocking as in not `async`; distinct from `torch.distributed`.

I suppose the reason logging and writing the results to file "fix" the issue while `sort` does not is because the former are not torch ops (and, therefore, not managed by the distributed process group) which forces synchronization.